# How to pass a value from Vue data to href?

Tags: vue.js, href

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<div v-for="r in rentals">
  <a bind-href="'/job/'r.id"> {{ r.job_title }} </a>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to add the value of `r.id` to the end of the `href` attribute so that I can make an API call. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 537, accepted):

You need to use `v-bind:` or its alias `:`. For example,

```
<a v-bind:href="'/job/'+ r.id">
```

or

```
<a :href="'/job/' + r.id">
```

Comment: Im getting a compile error with both even though it should work. Maybe it has there is a problem since it is inside a v-for?

Comment: It needed a "+". This worked                     <a :href="'/job/' + r.id">{{ r.job_title }}</a>

Comment: I ran into this same problem 4 years later and this answer solved it for me again. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I wanted to prevent click on the `tr` from a `table` when I clicking in an ' href` without a method. I used `.self` in the ' td` and moved the method from the `tr'  to each `td`. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838076/how-to-ignore-that-clicking-on-a-td-tag-does-not-automatically-redirect-me-to-an/74465289#74465289

Comment: In vue3 for href binding I use following in v-for loop:
<a :href="`/url/${categoryId}`">{{ item.title }}</a>

Answer (score 108):

Or you can do that with ES6 template literal:

```
<a :href="`/job/${r.id}`"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can concatenate your static value and dynamic value as string values, while binding `href`. Using your example:

```
<div v-for="r in rentals">
  <a :href="'/job/' + r.id"> {{ r.job_title }} </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display links coming from your state or store in Vue 2.0, you can do like this:

```
<a v-bind:href="''"> {{ url_link }} </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also help.

```
<a target="_blank" :href="r.reg_metadato">{{ r.reg_metadato }}</a>
```