# How do I display data returned from Laravel resource in Vue Component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am practicing Vue and am confused on how to handle data passing. I have a link in my Vue component `<a class="btn btn-success" :href="'/projectpage/' + project.id">Bid</a>` [Thanks to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899532/how-to-pass-a-value-from-vue-data-to-href). In my routes web.php I have this route `Route::get('/projectpage/{id}', 'ProjectController@projectPage');`. In my ProjectController I have this function

```
    public function projectPage($id){
       $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
       // return new ProjectResource($project);
       return view('project',['project'=>$project]);
}
```

When I return the ProjectResource it displays the JSON Data and when I return the view, it displays the view and the data that I want to be displayed. I however want to display the data from a vue component. The vue component to fetch the data and then display it on the blade page say like `<component></component>`. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are asking, you will have to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). You can install it by `npm install axios`

Next, check your `resource/js/bootstrap.js` file to make sure you have axios imported.

```
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

And, in your `resource/js/app.js` file add

```
require("./bootstrap");
```

Run `npm run dev`

Finally, add the script to your main .blade file `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

---

At the end, simply call via axios from a method

```
axios.get('route')
     .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data); // store this in a variable
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data);
      });
```

Your component call

`<YourComponent v-for="list in lists" />`

Keep me posted in the comments below. Cheers!

Comment: I have done this and am getting the json data but its not rendering in the component. Its not a list, its just a single project