# How to pass a variable in a href tag?

Tags: html, vue.js, environment-variables, href

I have an application in vue in which I show different links in the header.
depending on the environment the root of the link varies, so I have saved an environment variable with the value of this root of the link.
I import it in the component to use the reference to this variable, but I can't find the way to include it in the href tag.
in my component's script I import the config file where the variable is declared and return

```
<script>
import Config from './../../config.js';

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {      
      hoverHome: false,
      testUrl: Config.TEST_URL
    }
  },
```

the value brought by the environment variable at this time is https://www.test.sp, and in my template I try to use it but I don't find how to do it neither in case of being the only value nor combining it with a url termination

```
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link head" href=testUrl>Business</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link head" href=testUrl/shops>Shops</a>
  </li>
```

how can i use this variable inside the href tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind the **href** value using the  `v-bind:href` or shortly  `:href` for **v-bind**

So simply you can bind any variable that has some link to your href like

`<a v-bind:href="'/anylink/' + testUrl">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use v-bind: or its alias :. For example,

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link head" v-bind:href="testUrl">Business</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link head" v-bind:href="testUrl + '/shops'">Shops</a>
  </li>
```

or

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link head" :href="testUrl">Business</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link head" :href="testUrl + '/shops'">Shops</a>
  </li>
```

See [How to pass a value from Vue data to href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899532/how-to-pass-a-value-from-vue-data-to-href)