# Problem the symbol {{ }} in the dynamic link with vue inside file .cshtml

Tags: c#, vue.js, razor

I use vue inside file .cshtml and when I want to show the dynamic link the value of `{{item.id}}`  show as text, not as a value

```
<tr v-for="item in resultQuery">
   <td>{{item.nombre}}</td>
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
   <td>{{moment(item.FechaCambioEstado).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}</td>
   <td>
     <a href='~/Deudores/Detalle/{{item.id}}'>Ver más</a>
       More
     </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The error is this:
https://localhost:44366/Deudores/Detalle/%7B%7Bitem.id%7D%7D

Error in the console is this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

href="/Deudores/Detalle/{{item.id}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
```

[image]

Comment: "but doesn't work" is not an explanation of a problem and image in no way clarifies what HTML you want to see generated by that code. Please [edit] the post to explain the problem (like HTML does not match your expectations, some errors in C#/JS, something else)

Comment: Thanks for your commentary Now I explained with more details

Comment: You should look at [MCVE] guidance again - how one would know where that `item` is defined? There is no `item` in your .cshtml code... And make sure to understand what is *text* and what is *C# code* in CSHTML - the only piece of C# code is `@Url.Action("Detalle", "Deudores", new { id = item.id })` - we can't guess what `item` is from that - even less than C# compiler.

Comment: I use the `{{ item.id }}` in the `<td>` y the data I see in the table but in the line new `{ id = item.id }` say don't exist. Why? or What is a possible solution?

Comment: You did not read my previous comment :(... Let me repost -  the only piece of C# code is `@Url.Action("Detalle", "Deudores", new { id = item.id })` . I suspect you don't understand the distinction between C# code and plain text in CSHTML file - I don't have a good explanation link handy... Hopefully if you think about it and for example highlight printout of your code with "this is C# code" you could sort out what you are asking and what exactly your problem is. I'll try to find a link probably on weekend.

Comment: Now I understand and change the question, thanks.

Comment: Please show the error message as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: As far as the question goes, ASP.NET sees the URL with a `~` and rewrites it to use the virtual path of the application. When it does that, in URL encodes the rest. This all happens before Vue ever gets to see it. I don't know Vue, but you could just write some script to find `%7B%7Bitem.id%7D%7D` and replace it with the value of `item.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. The problem was Vue. I didn't use the `v-bind`.

```
<a v-bind:href="'/Deudores/Detalles'+ item.id">More</a>
```

The solution in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40899733/2400373